# Any way to add more then 1000 face in single faceList

Tags: azure, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am using microsoft cognitive service face API for my project for face recognision.

I want to add 1000+ faces in the single "FaceList" instead of creating 64 different face lists.

I will have more than 10,000+ users in a group. Then I want to use "Find Similar" API with all my photos in the same "FaceList" to find match faces.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, A face list still can have a maximum of 1000 faces **for now**. Also, you can only specify one unique candidate face list in the Find Similar request API **for now**.

We realize that it's very important to customers and Face API is more popular today. Azure cognitive Team has paid attention to this . You can also upvote this idea in [this UserVoice Page](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/430315-face/suggestions/32785054-support-for-more-than-1-000-faces-in-face-lists-in). If Cognitive Team has any process on this, you will be noticed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have already raised the question. [link](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-general-feedback/suggestions/32866888-1000-face)

Comment: @MayankPanchal . If this answer is helpful to you , you can accept it so that we can help more people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a personGroup then add the 1000+ face to the persons in this personGroup. And then use Identify to find the person matches with your input image.

The S0 tier subscriptions have these limits: 10,000 Persons per Person Group, 100M Persons total and 1M Person Groups per subscription.